# Detect i'm on android permission React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm using the AppState to reset the states of the App when the AppState is "background", but when I ask for a Permission, for example Camera or Location, the AppState change to "background", so it reset all my states. There's a way to control when the Pop Up permission appear so it doesn't reset the states on pop up Permissions?

```html
<TouchableOpacity
                                onPress={() => {
                                    setChangeAppState(false);
                                    FunctionsWorkersList.chooseSource(item);
                                }}>
```

Here i change the state for not doing nothing on background, but it keeps reseting me the states there:

```html
    useEffect(() => {
        if (changeAppState == false) {
            console.log("state changed")
        } else {
            const appStateListener = AppState.addEventListener(
                'change',
                nextAppState => {
                    if (
                        (nextAppState == 'background' ||
                            nextAppState == 'inactive') &&
                        changeAppState == false
                    ) {
                        navigation.dispatch(
                            CommonActions.reset({
                                index: 0,
                                routes: [
                                    { name: 'HomeWorkerScreen' },
                                    { name: 'GetLogsScreen' },
                                    { name: 'WorkersListScreen' },
                                    { name: 'CardsListScreen' },
                                ],
                            }),
                        );
                    }
                },
            );
            return () => {
                appStateListener?.remove();
            };
        }
    }, [changeAppState]);
```

It seems like don't have time to change the state?

Comment: when do you set ```changeAppState``` to true?

Comment: only on the declaration of the State.  const [changeAppState, setChangeAppState] = useState(true);

Comment: And when do you set false value?

Comment: At pressing the button, before executing the function  FunctionsWorkersList.chooseSource(item);

Comment: Look at first screenshot.

Comment: Where are you asking permission for camera and others?

Comment: Inside the FunctionsWorkersList.chooseSource(item);

Comment: In that function set your flag to true and when permission is granted, set it false again. And use the code i wrote in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a flag to denote whether the background state is because of permission popup or any other piece of code which will cause background state to trigger. And then reset your state accordingly.

here is sample based on your code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const appStateListener = AppState.addEventListener(
      'change',
      nextAppState => {
        if ((nextAppState == 'background' || nextAppState == 'inactive') && 
          (your_flag_which_will_be_true_if_are_asking_permission == false) {
          navigation.dispatch(
            CommonActions.reset({
              index: 0,
              routes: [
                { name: 'HomeWorkerScreen' },
                { name: 'GetLogsScreen' },
                { name: 'WorkersListScreen' },
                { name: 'CardsListScreen' }
              ]
            })
          );
        }
      }
    );
    return () => {
      appStateListener?.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you show me a example of it?  I hadn't understand it at all.

Comment: you must be doing ```PermissionsAndroid.request( PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA, ...)``` something like that. Set some value to a flag before this line.

And there must be a function which is resetting all your states. return from that function when the flag is set with above value and reset the flag value too before returning.

Comment: I edited my question to show you my example.